# Bottle.py serving larger images with a short delay results to zero length response

Tags: python, bottle

I have the defined the following static route in Bottle.py

```
@get('/create/new/image', apply=[auth_request])
def request_new_image():
   file = invoke_image_creation()
   return static_file(file, root='pics',
                      mimetype='image/jpg')
```

In the method `invoke_image_creation()` a simple event lock (`threading.Event`) is used to let the application block until the image is created. Then it should return the static file.

For small images this works, for larger (1280x720 with around 50 KB) it returns:

- HTTP 200
- no content in response
- content-length: 0
- MIME-type: image/jpg

The blocking only lasts for a moment, very much less than a second, just to make sure it's there.

What could cause that? Using a [simple routing static files function](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) works just fine with exactly the same picture. The only difference is, the file is there beforehand and its defined in the HTTP GET request.

Comment: Are you closing the file correctly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually this is not my call, because the image creation is done by a separate process and all I do is watching the file system for a change (inotify, create file event) and then I unlock the `threading.Event`. Hence, the file closing is done by the other process. But maybe there is some overlapping between file creation event and closing stream to the file?

Comment: Could there be a lag in the writing of the file to disk?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good question! I inserted a `time.sleep(2)` before the `return` statement and it works now. This is really ugly. Any suggestions for a cleaner solution?

Comment: @fp That makes sense, since this only happens to the *larger* images

Comment: Maybe using [os.fsync()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a delay between file opening and file data being flushed to disk, so if you are watching for a file creation event, you can easily return what is essentially still an empty file.

You need to either change your notification to listen for changes instead of new files, or make sure that new files are fully formed.

To do the latter, change the external process to create the file in a different location, then move the file when the image has been created into the location you are watching. If the two locations are on the same partition, the move will be atomic; if your file monitoring sees the file appear it's guaranteed that it'll be non-empty at that point.

Or, pseudo-python-code, in your separate process:

```
import shutil

createImage(locA, filename)
shutil.move(os.path.join(locA, filename), locB)
```

And watch `locB`.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot modify the code of the process I am using for the image creation. Until now I have used the file create event in order to trigger the events. This create file event is followed by a file modified event and I believe I get this event from inotify, when to the file was written.

Comment: @MaxRhan: You cannot add a wrapper process? Small script that uses `subprocess.call()`, then does the move? Hell, even a bash script?

Comment: I don't think that is an option, since this process does a lot more than just create the image, it's not a command-line utility. But, what did help was overriding the `on_modified` method instead of the `on_created` method, since the former one is only invoked after the file stream is closed again. That's what I wanted in the first place. Feel free to add this to your answer, I gladly accept. Both are viable solutions.

Comment: @MaxRhan: There you go, slight edit to include listening for changed files instead. :-)